# Problem with meta key in Emacs

Tags: terminal-emacs, input-method

I use Emacs in command-line always on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. And I use two languages frequently. Bengali/Bangla and English. Problem is when I use Bangla, commands with Ctrl as modifier work fine (e.g. C-x C-s) but with Meta they are not. e.g. M-x is not opening the minibuffer instead Emacs understands it as M-ূ. Is there any way to use Meta like Ctrl?

Comment: Do you also have the problem if you use the non-command line version of Emacs?  (i.e., is this a terminal problem or an Emacs problem?)

Comment: Emacs problem. All the same.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can use `ESC` as a prefix in the same manner that you would use meta as a modifier, like so:

`ESC x`

Note that you don't have to hold escape down, you can press the two keys sequentially.

You can also do things like `ESC C-e` to simulate `C-M-e`.

Comment: Esc does the same. Actually I need ctrl-like behavior in alt. That means when I am pressing ctrl my current input method is being ignored so commands works fine. In the case of alt or esc system do not ignoring input method.